# After upgrading to Ubuntu 14.04, my shortcuts keys and media keys no longer work

Tags: gnome, upgrade, keyboard, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout

I just upgraded from 13.10 to 14.04 (GNOME interface) and none of the shortcut key combinations or Fn+F(#) controls seem to be working any more (not even the default ones, like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> for terminal). Additionally, I have an HP wireless keyboard with extra media control and volume toggle buttons. These no longer function either. Going to Settings->Keyboard->Shortcuts and attempting manual changes doesn't work.

What changed in 14.04 to cause this? I never had any problems at all with Saucy! I didn't change my keyboard configuration or anything like that, and when I tested the keys with showkey they all worked, so something got lost with the keyboard mapping when the upgrade happened.

Answer (score 3):

Killing `unity-settings-daemon` and running `gnome-settings-daemon` worked for me 
, or running:

```
gnome-settings-daemon --replace
```

But it's not a persistent solution. It affects all keyboard shortcuts set via 
SystemSettings...→Keyboard→Shortcuts. Running Ubuntu 14.04.

(also maybe interesting: some shortcuts that were set before updating from 13.04 to 14.04 still worked, but as soon as I reassign them in the System Settings, they stop working with `unity-settings-daemon`)

Comment: This can lead to the loss of data. Be sure to save all your data and close all programs before doing it.

Comment: @pvc, can you explain which data might be lost?

Comment: @TylerCollier Everything that is not saved.  In my case whole X server restarted few seconds after running that command.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the bug report https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity-control-center/+bug/1302885
& here you go, this should do the trick...

The problem is that an incorrect string is set in dconf key: (Example)

Original (working) value:

```
gsettings get org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys volume-up
'XF86AudioRaiseVolume'
```

After running "unity-control-center keyboard", and setting the shortcut for
volume-up key:

```
gsettings get org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys volume-up
'AudioRaiseVolume'
```

The new value misses the "XF86" part of the string, and does not work.

You can get the key working again by resetting the value, with:

```
gsettings reset org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys volume-up
```

to reset key using GUI, you can install dconf-tools:

```
sudo apt-get install dconf-tools
```

Comment: This worked well for me after SystemSettings...→Keyboard→Shortcuts remapping broke the Media keys functionality.  The 3 commands to restore Audio control were: gsettings reset org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys volume-up & gsettings reset org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys volume-down & gsettings reset org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys volume-mute .

Comment: Worked here too. I just used Dconf, browsed to Org/Gnome/Settings-Daemon/Plugins, then hit the "reset" button on all the media entries. Thanks for this.

Answer (score 2):

As stated by @robin-hood, it looks like a known bug on [Launchpad](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity-control-center/+bug/1302885).

According to the thread there, the current simple fix is to...

1. Open terminal (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd>)
2. Type the following two commands to reset the volume keys on your
   keyboard...

   ```
   gsettings reset org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys volume-up
   gsettings reset org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys volume-down
   ```

It worked for me, hope it works for you too.

Comment: "volume-mute" can be used, too

Answer (score 2):

I've tried a number of proposed solutions (for Ubuntu 14.04), however this worked for me.  From a terminal type (or copy paste..  Note you need to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> to paste in to a terminal);

```
gsettings reset org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys volume-up
gsettings reset org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys volume-down
gsettings reset org.gnome.settings-daemon.plugins.media-keys volume-mute
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, updatet from Ubuntu Gnome 13.10 to 14.04. Something happened at this process, so gnome3 didn't work properly. I could control my background light, but without OSD, volume buttons, other fn-keys didn't work and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> didn't open the terminal. So I decided to upgrade gnome-shell to 3.12, I realised, that my main gnome3 ppa's were disabled (which is normal while upgrading Ubuntu) so you could also try enabling those by typing:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3
```

afterwards, to update gnome3 type:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

If you want to try gnome 3.12 add the main repository but afterwards also add the staging by typing

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:gnome3-team/gnome3-staging
```

and type:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

afterwards.

Reboot and everything should work!

good luck!

Answer (score 0):

On Xubuntu 14.04 I had to (re)enable `gnome-settings-daemon` to get the media keys working again.

Comment: Ah, that might be it.

Hm. I'm getting this message when I try running `gnome-settings-daemon --debug`:


`** (gnome-settings-daemon:4161): WARNING **: Name taken or bus went away - shutting down


** (gnome-settings-daemon:4161): DEBUG: Shutting down


** (gnome-settings-daemon:4161): DEBUG: SettingsDaemon finished`

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the gnome environment installed, but still ran into the same symptoms. I'm not certain why, since my install has been working fine for a few months, but just today all the shortcuts in the "Keyboard settings" ceased to work. As is hinted at briefly at the bottom of [this thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2218418), there seems to be a bad gnome configuration. I tried removing my `~/.gconf` folder (after making a backup first!) and logging out/in, and that fixed my problem. The full steps to fix were:

1. Open up your home folder by pressing the Windows (or meta) key or by clicking on the first icon in the doc, then typing `Files` and opening the Files application.
2. Show hidden files and folders by pressing **Ctrl+H**.
3. Find the `.gconf` folder and rename it to `.gconfg.bak`.
4. Hide hidden files and folders again by pressing **Ctrl+H**.
5. Log out of your account and back in. while many of your settings will be back to default, your shortcuts should work again.